# Discord Application via HTML not sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, discord.js

I have recently been working on a HTML website that would send a discord webhook to a channel, I thought I had everything correct but for some reason, it just refreshes the page when I try to submit.

I've already tried to move things around and research how to use variables in strings and such, no luck.

```js
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Elly Hangouts | Mod App</title>

</head>


<body>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.input').focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".label-txt").addClass('label-active');
  });

  $(".input").focusout(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).parent().find(".label-txt").removeClass('label-active');
    };
  });

});
</script>

<form>
  <label>
    <p class="label-txt">DISCORD NAME AND TAG</p>
    <input id="user" type="text" class="input">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <p class="label-txt">FIRST NAME</p>
    <input id="firstname" type="text" class="input">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <p class="label-txt">WHY DO YOU WANT TO BE A MODERATOR?</p>
    <input id="q1" type="text" class="input">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
    <label>
    <p class="label-txt">WHY SHOULD WE CHOOSE YOU OVER OTHERS?</p>
    <input id="q2" type="text" class="input">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
      <label>
    <p class="label-txt">WHAT TIMEZONE ARE YOU IN?</p>
    <input id="q3" type="text" class="input">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
      <label>
    <p class="label-txt">DO YOU HAVE ANY EXPERIENCE? IF SO, GIVE A LIST</p>
    <input id="q4" type="text" class="input">
    <div class="line-box">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <button type="Submit">submit</button>
</form>




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#Submit').click(function(e) {
        var url = "hidden";
        var content = "**New Application Submitted** \n \n Discord Name and Tag: $(#user) \n \n First Name: $(#firstname) \n \n Why do you want to be a moderator? \n $(#q1) \n \n Why should we choose you over others? \n $(#q2) \n \n What timezone are you in? \n $(#q3) \n \n Do you have any experience? \n $(#q4)";
        var username = "Moderator Applications";
        $.post(url,
    {


    "content":content,
    "username": username,


    },
        function(){
            Materialize.toast('Message Sent!', 4000)
        });
        });
    });
    </script>

<div class="hiddendiv common"></div><div id="toast-container"></div></body> -- This doesn't show.
</html>
```

I do not get any error messages ( that can be seen. ) and the page just refreshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `submit` action on a form is supposed to refresh the page, that's how form submit works. What I would do is set an ID to the button, remove the submit function, then use jQuery to detect the button click and send the data.